# JSF client behavior set on composite component is triggered twice in some conditions

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, listener, composite-component

Let's take the following example:

The composite component is as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

    <!-- INTERFACE -->
    <cc:interface>
        <cc:clientBehavior name="click" targets="button" event="click"/>
    </cc:interface>

    <!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
    <cc:implementation>
        <span id="#{cc.clientId}">
            <h:commandButton id="button" value="Press me">
                <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{bean.helloFromComposite()}"/>
            </h:commandButton>
        </span>
    </cc:implementation>
</html>
```

And the using page is as follows:

```
<h:form id="form">                   
    <my:button id="my-button">
        <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{bean.HelloFromPage()}"/>
    </my:button>
</h:form>
```

Then, when I click on the button the bean logs:

- Hello from composite
- Hello from page
- Hello from composite
- Hello from page

Reproduced on Glassfish 4.1.1 with Omnifaces 2.5.1 and Primefaces 6.0.

If I change my using page as follows, then the problem disappears:

```
<h:form id="form">                   
    <my:button id="my-button">
        <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{bean.HelloFromPage()}" execute="@none"/>
    </my:button>
</h:form>
```

When I click on the button the bean now logs:

- Hello from composite
- Hello from page

I have two questions:

1. Is it a known behavior?
2. Is the sequence "Hello from composite", "Hello from page" by design? It's fine by me, as in my opinion the ajax behavior inside the composite is more specific (and should be executed first) than the ajax behavior specified in the using page.

**Edit:**
I can reproduce the problem in a very simple way, as follows:

```
<h:form>                   
    <h:commandButton>
        <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{bean.helloOne()}"/>
        <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{bean.helloTwo()}"/>
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Solved by adding an execute @none attribute in the second AJAX call:

```
<h:form>                   
    <h:commandButton>
        <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{bean.helloOne()}"/>
        <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{bean.helloTwo()}" execute="@none"/>
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Could there be a confusion between the button is 'clicked' and the button is 'executed'?